# Same prefix, multiple namespace in XML - How to add element attrib without affecting other in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have the below input XML:

```
<host xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.1" >

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>

</host>
```

As you can see, xmlns is used for two namespaces , **"urn:jboss:domain:4.1"** and **"urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3"**

I would like to add an attribute to **host** element

Below is my code in Python:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def parse_xml():
    ET.register_namespace('','urn:jboss:domain:4.1')
    tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
        for elements in tree.iter():
        if "host" in elements.tag :
            elements.attrib['name'] = "slaveOne"
            print elements.attrib
            tree.write('sample.xml')
```

The above code changes the XML as below:

```
<host xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.1" xmlns:ns1="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3" name="slaveOne">

    <profile>
        <ns1:subsystem>
            <ns1:expose-resolved-model />
            <ns1:expose-expression-model />
            <ns1:remoting-connector />
        </ns1:subsystem>
    </profile>

</host>
```

> tree.write('sample.xml')

Changes all elements belonging to same prefix in this case

> ET.register_namespace('','urn:jboss:domain:4.1')

- How do i isolate the changes only to **host** element

Comment: Why not just replace last bracket ">" with "name=... >" in first line of file? Xml file is just a text file in your situation. Tell me more if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ar7max , yes it can be done as well. The xml file in my situation is a configuration file. Its the same configuration file that you would find in  JBoss Application server. Quick way for now would be to follow ,find-replace approach. But in future i will be heavily modifying this XML, so wanted to know solution using XML parsing in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [minidom](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.dom.minidom.html):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("sample.xml")

#getElementsByTagName returns NodeList
#grab first
host = doc.getElementsByTagName("host")[0]

#set attr -> value
#look at setAttributeNS in minidom docs for namespaces 
host.setAttribute('name', '123')

#write to file
with open('sample2.xml', 'w') as xmlfile:
    doc.writexml(xmlfile)
```

Take a look at [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax) package and this [XML Processing Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.html) page  too.